# How to hide red lambda symbol beside line numbers/breakpoints

Tags: intellij-idea

Is there any way to hide the red lambda symbol that shows up beside where the line numbers/breakpoints usually are?

[image]

Comment: What type of file is this? Can you reveal the code next to these symbols?

Comment: I don't even know what that symbol is for -- I'm not aware of ever having seen it before. Can you expand your question a bit with some explanation of what we're looking at? The search term 'red-lambda' returns no associations with intellij.

Comment: Sorry should have been more specific, as far as I can tell it shows up any time there is a lambda function. This is in Java 8, not sure if it would show for other languages as well...

Comment: FYI, they're hoping to change the color eventually to not be RED: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-147324

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable at File>Settings>Editor>General>Gutter Icons>Common

its a reference to navigate to super method